# What am i doing wrong with pd.pivot() or pd.pivot_table()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe of style:

```
     item1  item2 item3
idx1 val1   val1  val1
idx2 val2   val2  val2
idx3 val3   val3  val3
idx4 val4   val4  val4
idx5 val5   val5  val5
```

I'm trying to swap it around so that it looks like this:

```
      idx1  idx2  idx3  idx4  idx5
item1 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
item2 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
item3 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
```

Essentially, I want the indexes to become the columns and the columns to become the index.  However when I try doing something like `df = pivot_table(df, index=df.columns, columns=df.index)` I get an error that says `Grouper and axis must be same length` I'm not certain how to swap these around. Any help would be appreciated on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by transposing the dataframe, either by referring to its transpose attribute (`df.T`) or by using its transpose method (`df.transpose()`):

```
>>> df
     item1 item2 item3
idx1  val1  val1  val1
idx2  val2  val2  val2
idx3  val3  val3  val3
idx4  val4  val4  val4
idx5  val5  val5  val5
>>> df = df.T
>>> df
       idx1  idx2  idx3  idx4  idx5
item1  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
item2  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
item3  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
```

Comment: thank you so much! I was so confused for so long on this!